# Non linear first order ODE in in $\mathbb{R}^2$ 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the system of ODEs 
$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} x' = ax+ by^2, & x(0) = x_0\\ y' = ay +bx^2, & y(0) = y_0  \end{matrix} \right. $$

where $x, y :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}.$
I wonder whether there is, in general, $F$ such that $F(x,y) =0.$ 
For example, if $a =0,$ and $b \neq  0,$ we can write 
$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{y^2}{x^2},$$ which implies that 
$$x^3- y^3 + c = 0$$ for some constant $c.$

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: Do you mean a system of two *complex* differential equations?

Comment: $x,y$ are complex valued functions

Answer (score 0):

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} x' = ax+ by^2, & x(0) = x_0\\ y' = ay +bx^2, & y(0) = y_0  \end{matrix} \right.$$
Multiply first equation by $x^2$ and second equation by $y^2$
$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} x^2x' = ax^3+ by^2x^2 & . \\ y'y^2 = ay^3 +bx^2y^2 & .  \end{matrix} \right.$$
$$x'x^2-ax^3=y'y^2-ay^3$$
$$\frac 13 (x^3)'-ax^3=\frac 13 (y^3)'-ay^3$$
$$\frac 13( x^3-y^3)'=a(x^3-y^3)$$
You can integrate, substitute $z=x^3-y^3$
$$z'=3az$$
$$ \implies x^3(t)=y^3(t)+Ke^{3at}$$

---

You can try to integrate the differential equation with exactness 
$$\frac {dx}{dy}=\frac {ax+by^2}{ay+bx^2}$$
$$({ay+bx^2})dx-({ax+by^2})dy=0$$
$$Pdx+Qdy=0 \implies \partial_y P=a, \partial_x Q=-a $$ $$\implies \partial_y P -\partial_x Q=2a$$
Try an integrating factor $z=x^3-y^3$

And the formula for the integratinf factor $z=z(x,y)$ is 
$$\boxed {\frac {d\mu}{\mu}=\frac {\partial_y P- \partial_x Q}{Q \partial_x z -P \partial_y z}}$$
$$\frac {d\mu}{\mu}=\frac {2a dz}{Q \partial_x z -P \partial_y z}$$
$$\frac {d\mu}{\mu}=-\frac {2 dz}{3z}$$
$$\mu =\frac 1 {\sqrt[3]{z^2}}$$
$$\mu (x,y) =\frac 1 {\sqrt[3]{(x^3-y^3)^2}}$$

Comment: This yields an invariant $F(x,y,t)=0$, not $F(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Yes true @Did ...I added a line

Comment: What is $\mu$ ? The second argument is true if $x, y$ are complex  valued functions, right ?

Comment: $\mu$ is an integrating factor ..so the differential becomes ecact and you can therefore solve it with exactness @A.PI

Comment: Thank you for the answer...  I'm not expert in diff. forms. I'd be really very grateful if you add more details to the last two lines.

Comment: @A.PI  It's a well known formula for integrating factor...you have first kind that depend on x or y and second kind that depends on both x and y...Here the integrating factor depends on both x and y...since$ z=x^3-y^3$ ...Maybe if you never tried that you should sart with simple differential equation with integrating factor that only depend on x or y...

Comment: OK ... and what is the corresponding $F$ in this case ?

Comment: Take a look at Paul's note here on this method @A.PI

Comment: Could you activate the link on "here" :)?

Comment: Yes sure...@A.PI I added some lines in my answer...Here is the link to Paul' s notes http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Exact.aspx

Comment: @Isham Thank you very much :)

Comment: yw @A.PI not sure you will find a solution to your system..it looks simple but it's far from being simple to solve... Good luck

Comment: in advanced step I'll be interested in the case where $y_0 = \bar{x_0}.$ I'm not sure too if this will make the situation easier.

Comment: not sure it makes things easier..did you try mathematica or wolfram alpha ? @A.PI

Comment: no... how can this help in this domain ? I usually us wolfram to check some integrals.

Comment: wolfram alpha is a nice soft...even for differential equation ...not sure here it will give an analytical solution but most of the time it gives nice answers...@A.PI

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27+%3D+y+%2B+x%5E2,+x%27+%3D+x%2By%5E2

Comment: Oh it means the solution is really complicated...because wa is really good soft for diff equations @A.PI